CodeSnap settings not showing on VSCode
I want to change the way the codesnap screenshots show but when I click on the extension and press Extension Settings, the settings appear for less than a second and then they disapear and it only shows "No Settings Found".
I wanted to customize the CodeSnap extension but the settings for it appear and then dissapear.
